# ListView with ArrayAdapter and EditText how to store changed data

Tags: android, listview, view, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I have this issue:

I created a `Listview` with a custom `ArrayAdapter` composed by 3 `EditText`, on the activity where the `Listview` is inserted there is a button for add new line into the `Listview` cloned by the last one.

> The behavior of the list is that when I click  the ADD button all the
>   changes made to the lines of the listview are lost.

I figure out the I need to insert some code for save the changes into the ArrayAdapter's objects, but I can't fine a good solution for do it.

Can you pleas give me some advices?

Thank you.

ArrayAdapter

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Exercise_p_obj> {

private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Exercise_p_obj> listExercises = new ArrayList<Exercise_p_obj>();

public ExerciseAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<Exercise_p_obj> objects) {
    super(context, resourceId, objects);
    resource = resourceId;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    listExercises = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Recuperiamo l'oggetti che dobbiamo inserire a questa posizione
    final Exercise_p_obj exercise_p = getItem(position);

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.et_reps = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_reps);
        holder.et_kg   = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_kg);
        holder.et_rest = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_rest);
        holder.bt_del  = (Button)   v.findViewById(R.id.bt_del);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.et_reps.setText(String.valueOf(exercise_p.getReps()));
    holder.et_kg.setText(String.valueOf(exercise_p.getWeight()));
    holder.et_rest.setText(String.valueOf(exercise_p.getRest()));

    holder.bt_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listExercises.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
 EditText et_reps;
 EditText et_kg;
 EditText et_rest;
 Button   bt_del;}}
```

Main Activity

```
    public class ExerciseCreate extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
ListView listView;
Button btAdd;
Button btDel;
ExerciseAdapter exerciseAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.createexercise);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exerciselistView);
    btAdd    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_add);
    toolbar  = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

    exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseAdapter(this, R.layout.rowexercise,new ArrayList<Exercise_p_obj>());
    exerciseAdapter.add(new Exercise_p_obj(1,1,1,1,1,1));

    listView.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final int count = exerciseAdapter.getCount();
            Exercise_p_obj clone = exerciseAdapter.getItem(count - 1);
            exerciseAdapter.add(new Exercise_p_obj(0, clone.getId_exer_h(), clone.getReps(), clone.getSecs(), clone.getWeight(), clone.getRest()));
        }
    });

}}
```

Comment: in the MainActivity try adding excerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Jerry I tried to add that method, but still have the same issue. I think is something about the update of the exercise_p object.

Comment: I solved using a TextWatcher on EditView.
  

 `holder.et_reps.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                exercise_p.setReps(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString()));
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Use separate list with data. When you want to add new item you firstly add it to list and then you need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

```
public class ExerciseCreate extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ListView listView;
    Button btAdd;
    Button btDel;
    ExerciseAdapter exerciseAdapter;
    List<Exercise_p_obj> items = new ArrayList<Exercise_p_obj>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createexercise);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exerciselistView);
        btAdd    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_add);
        toolbar  = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

        items.add(new Exercise_p_obj(1,1,1,1,1,1));
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseAdapter(this, R.layout.rowexercise,items);
        listView.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int count = items.size();
                Exercise_p_obj clone = items.get(count - 1);
                items.add(new Exercise_p_obj(0, clone.getId_exer_h(), clone.getReps(), clone.getSecs(), clone.getWeight(), clone.getRest()));
                exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ярослав Зозуля seems to not work, in debug I saw the items ArrayList still be not updated according to the new value of the EditText. I guess that I need to send the value inserted into the EditText to the items when the user make a change.
For this reason I tried using the TextWatcher.